# How to get an array/list from appsettings

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .net 7 console application. As part of my `main()` I am trying to access an array from my `appSetting.json` file but I cannot seem to read the contents and bind it to an array/list object.

**appSettings structure:**

```
{
  "Settings":{
    "Name": "test123",
    "IsValid": true,
    "Counter": 123
  },
  "Sites": [
    {
      "site": "US",
      "dateFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy",
      "timeFormat": "HH:mm:ss"
    },
    {
      "site": "IE",
      "dateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "timeFormat": "HH:mm:ss"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Main():**

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using var host = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args).Build();

    //IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var settings = new Settings();
    // [Good] This object is hydrated from appSettings.
    config.GetSection("Settings").Bind(settings);

    var siteDetails = new List<SiteDetails>();
    // [Bad] This item is an empty list
    config.GetSection("Sites").Bind("Sites", siteDetails);
    
    //removed for brevity
}
```

**Sites.cs**

```
public class Sites
{
    public string site { get; set; }
    public string dateFormat { get; set; }
    public string timeFormat { get; set; }
}
```

**Settings.cs**

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsValue { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show class Settings

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi - I've updated the original post with the `Settings` and `Sites` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get information in two ways

Get Sites

1.

```
var configSectiofffn = config.GetSection("Sites").Get<Sites[]>();
```

2. 

```
var siteDetails = new List<Sites>();
config.GetSection("Sites").Bind( siteDetails);
```

get settings

1.

```
var settings = new Settings();
config.GetSection("Settings").Bind(settings);
```

2. 

```
var settingsnew = config.GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
```

aslo,Your Json file has not  ']' in the end

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "Name": "test123",
    "IsValid": true,
    "Counter": 123
  },
  "Sites": [
    {
      "site": "US",
      "dateFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy",
      "timeFormat": "HH:mm:ss"
    },
    {
      "site": "IE",
      "dateFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
      "timeFormat": "HH:mm:ss"
    }
  ]
}
```

My  Configuration Main

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
 //.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

 .AddEnvironmentVariables();

IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
```

Comment: The missing closing `]`was a mistake when posting the OP. My local version does not have that missing closing `]`. I have updated the OP. I have also tried all your suggestions and `Sites` is still `null`.

Comment: Do you use my Configuration?can you add your  code in github than i can test?

Comment: There was an issue in the json contents of the appSettings file. Thanks for the answer as it led me to double-check the appSettings.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of
`config.GetSection("Sites").Bind("Sites", siteDetails);`
you should either use
`config.GetSection("Sites").Bind(siteDetails);`
or
`config.Bind("Sites", siteDetails);`

You are first getting the "Sites" section and then again specifying to find "Sites" section when you chain `Bind("Sites", siteDetails)`